# "Secretariat" vs. "Directorate"

Tags: etymology

The office establishment where the Secretaries (say, of a Government) sit is called:

> "Secretariat" (without "e" in the end of the word).

Then, why does the office establishment where a Director (say, of a Government) sits is called:

> "Directorate" (with "e" in the end of the word)?

Why this difference? Has etymology anything to say in the issue?

Comment: Did you create the tag? It should be "spelling", not "speeling".

Comment: @Rathony - Sorry! I committed a mistake in that I accidently typed "speeling" in place  of "spelling". I am sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No worry, I think it could be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little time spent with the *OED* reveals the following.  *Secretariat* is a late (1811) borrowing from the French *secrétariat*.  Similarly-formed words borrowed much earlier, pre-1400, e.g., *estat*, picked up a final *e* after that date if their final vowel came to be pronounced long.  Similarly-formed words invented after 1400, like *directorate* (b. ca 1830) were pronounced similarly and spelled by analogy with a final *e*.

So apparently we borrowed *secretariat* from the French, and kept the French short final *a*, requiring no appended *e*.

We could have borrowed *directorat* from the French, but instead we apparently coined *directorate* from *director* + -*ate* by analogy with words like *estate* -- the long final voiced vowel requiring the final unvoiced *e*.